# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop performance - setting CPU frequency governor to performance

Tags: 16.04

Edit: Adding PC specs in case it helps.

```
i7-5820k 
x99P-SLI
32GB DDR4
GTX 970
```

I've been experiencing sub-par performance on a fresh install of 16.04 and after some research, learned about `cpupower` and CPU frequency governors. By default my CPU driver is `intel_ptstate` and my frequency governor is `powersave`. My machine performed noticeably faster after I manually set the governor to `performance` as it keeps my CPU operating around 3.30 Ghz vs 1.20 Ghz.

I also tested the older `acpi-cpufreq` driver by disabling the `intel_pstate` driver in Grub. It is now using the `ondemand` governor, but performance is basically the same: poor.

Here is the output of `cpupower frequency-info`

```
tommy@desktop:~$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.30 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.30 GHz, 3.30 GHz, 3.10 GHz, 3.00 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.30 GHz.
              The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 3.30 GHz:3.98%, 3.30 GHz:0.00%, 3.10 GHz:0.26%, 3.00 GHz:0.17%, 2.80 GHz:0.31%, 2.70 GHz:0.23%, 2.50 GHz:0.29%, 2.40 GHz:0.41%, 2.20 GHz:0.52%, 2.10 GHz:0.59%, 1.90 GHz:0.99%, 1.80 GHz:1.52%, 1.60 GHz:2.68%, 1.50 GHz:5.51%, 1.30 GHz:16.70%, 1.20 GHz:65.84%  (14777)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

<strike>Two</strike> Three questions:

- Should I be changing the governors like this?
- Some further research said that you shouldn't force performance with the intel_pstate driver. Is this true?
- If it's ok, how do I permanently set the governor to performance? I tried making a systemd service that set it at boot, but I'm not sure if it's working. It sets the governor to performance at boot, then changes it to powersave after a few minutes. This is when using the `intel_pstate` driver.

Here is the contents of the service `cpupower.service` that I created.

```
tommy@desktop:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/cpupower.service 

[Unit]
Description=CPU performance

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cpupower -c all frequency-set -g performance

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I hope this kind of makes sense! If anyone can provide some help, and help me understand the bigger picture of what's going on, I'd be extremely grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 3 questions:

> Should I be changing the governors like this?

Sure, if that is what you want to do. The cost is higher energy consumption. Note that even using the `performance` governor the CPU itself can backoff the pstate (performance state) under very low load.

> ```
> Some further research said that you shouldn't force performance with the intel_pstate driver. Is this true?
> ```

One shouldn't notice a great lot of difference between the `powersave` and `performance` CPU frequency governors using the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver. However, and apparently, you seems to have some sort of unique work flow that accentuates the difference. To answer your question: You can do whatever you want and whatever makes sense for your application.

> If it's ok, how do I permanently set the governor to performance? I
>   tried making a systemd service that set it at boot, but I'm not sure
>   if it's working. It sets the governor to performance at boot, then
>   changes it to powersave after a few minutes. This is when using the
>   intel_pstate driver.

Ubuntu uses a script, `/etc/init.d/ondemand`, to change the governor to `ondemand` (or `powersave` if there is no `ondemand`) after 1 minute. So you'll have to delete, or modify it, or add some other boot script that sleeps for more than 1 minute before changing the governor back.

The default, defined by the Ubuntu kernel configuration file, is the `performance` governor during boot.

Comment: This is great info! I'm not super familiar with this, so do I need to disable whatever is calling the ondemand script? Wouldn't deleting or changing permissions on the file cause errors ... or does everything within init.d just get run on boot?

Comment: @tomster2300:  I do not think you would disable whatever is calling the ondemand script. If it were me, I would just edit the script to do what I want, which in your case is do nothing.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I backed up the script and deleted the original and it looks like it's working. I'm sure it'll get added back with a system update, so I'll probably end up editing it as you suggested, but it's working for now.