# Lower graphic gaming performance than on Windows

Tags: games, intel-graphics, performance

I use Ubuntu 17.04 running on my EliteBook 8460p.
CPU: i5 2520m
GPU: Intel HD 3000

When I play Team Fortress 2 on my laptop I get FPS drops and mainly lower FPS than on Windows, but I noticed that my laptop is not running hot and the fans aren't loud like on Windows. Is there any way to check that or fix it? Also I'm not sure that Intel turbo boost is working properly.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the output of `lscpu`, `ubuntu-drivers devices` and `lsblk -k | grep -A3 VGA` please?

Answer (score 1):

Install some packages.

```
sudo apt install cpufrequtils sysfsutils
```

Run the command `cpufreq-info` to show the available cpufreq governors. Change the CPU scaling governor from *powersave* to *performance*<sup>[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854017/ubuntu-16-04-desktop-performance-setting-cpu-frequency-governor-to-performance)</sup>. Edit `/etc/default/cpufrequtils` (you might need to create it if it doesn't exist). Specify the governor with the GOVERNOR variable:

```
# valid values: userspace conservative powersave ondemand performance
# get them from cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors 
GOVERNOR="performance"
```

The sysfs values will be configured in `/etc/sysfs.conf` to  keep the governor settings between boots.

Comment: I don't think that an Intel CPU using pstate has "conservative" governor.

Comment: This means that you either disabled it manually, or it is a very old CPU.

Comment: And also why "conservative" can improve performance? The default is "ondemand", "conservative" should be slower.